# Flutter TextFormField validator message should the textfields position remain fixed or changed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, uitextfield

When we validate a TextFormField should the validation error message push the TextFieldForm under the first one below it or not? What is the best practice? Should there be enough space between the TextFormFields to show the error message?

My senior advised me to just show a red border without an error message, but I'm not sure about that as it limits accessibility, any opinions?

I've tried spaceing out the fields manually but it doesn't look good, I'm expecting there's a standard for this issue but I'm not what is it.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextFormField` doesn't need to change its location for the error message to show.
I believe the validator places itself below the form field so you can just simply return a string.

If you want to customize it, you can:

```
String errorMessage = "";

Column(
   children:[
      TextFormField(
         ...
      ),
      Text(errorMessage, style...)
   ]
)
```

You can do `setState(){}` inside of the validator when an error occurs.